# Is it possible to call searchpair or searchpairpos on string instead of current buffer?

Tags: vimscript, search

searchpair or searchpairpos works only on current buffer.

Are there similar functions work on string instead of buffer?

Comment: Good Question  I just implemented it manually

Comment: I did something similar a couple of months ago. I have only recently found this function by accident.

Comment: Well, if there were and they didn't have a name containing 'searchpair' then the dev should be ashamed of themselves.

Comment: No, as far as I know not possible.